# How to simply point my localhost(127.0.0.1) to my /home/user/ dir?

Tags: networking

How do I simply point my localhost to my home directory? When I type 127.0.0.1 on browser then it will redirect to my Home dir.

Comment: Ummm, it sounds like you want a webserver and to set your "DocumentRoot" to your home dir.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are right! Because I want to test my FTP program. But I don't know why it is not allowed me to browse the dir. Please advice

Comment: Wait, why FTP? Ftp://user:pass@localhost/ is the usual ftp url, but FTP is inherently insecure.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I want to test FTP to local directory for testing purpose instead of permanently use it. Should I install a web server application such as apache and setup the ftp ?

Answer (score 1):

To test your FTP program you could simply use the sftp protocol and point it to your localhost.

For example, in nautilus you would go to *Connect to Server* and enter the location `sftp://localhost`. Just enter your login info and you will be automatically taken to your home directory.
Now, this also applies for the usage of your ftp program. Make sure it supports sftp.